# How to get Id Form this JSON string

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I am trying to get Id for the below JSON string. but I am getting value as Undefined.

**JSON:**

```
Responce:: {"sobjectsAndStatus":[{"sObject":{"sobjectType":"Cost__c","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD","Category_Type__c":"","Comments__c":"","Units_Usage__c":1,"Rate_Per_Unit__c":0,"From_Address__c":null,"To_Address__c":null,"Account__c":"a0B4C000003AeBVUA0","Adjusted_Units__c":1,"Id":"a0O4C000001Q8LBUA0"},"status":"successful"}],"errorArrays":[]}
```

What I have tried:

```
var currentcosresp  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Responce));
console.log('var--> '+JSON.stringify(currentcosresp['Id']));
```

Any help will be thankful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to stringify and parse, you don't have JSON, you have a JavaScript Object (the former is a string, the latter is a real object you can use directly). You can do the following:

```
var id = Response.sobjectsAndStatus[0].sObject.Id;
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I tried and with the below script, it's working fine -

```
currentcosresp["sobjectsAndStatus"][0].sObject.Id
```

JS on browser -

```
var response = '{"sobjectsAndStatus":[{"sObject":{"sobjectType":"Cost__c","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD","Category_Type__c":"","Comments__c":"","Units_Usage__c":1,"Rate_Per_Unit__c":0,"From_Address__c":null,"To_Address__c":null,"Account__c":"a0B4C000003AeBVUA0","Adjusted_Units__c":1,"Id":"a0O4C000001Q8LBUA0"},"status":"successful"}],"errorArrays":[]}';
var currentcosresp  = JSON.parse(response );
console.log('Id -' , currentcosresp["sobjectsAndStatus"][0].sObject.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting undefined because the Id value is nested
you should try

```
 console.log('var--> '+JSON.stringify(currentcosresp['sobjectsAndStatus']['sObject']['id'])
```